# configuring similarity algorithms elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to change default similarity algorithm of elastic search

I viewed this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-similarity.html#default-base

but I don't know how set this config by rest api or config file or etc...

I also viewed this link:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/changing-similarities.html

but in this link changing the similarity type when building property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can change the default similarity of an index when you create the index as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "http://<server>/<index>" -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "similarity": {
      "default": { 
        "type": "BM25"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If an index already exists it requires a rebuild since at the moment it is not possible to dynamically update the similarity of an index as mentioned in this  :[open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6727)

You can change the  default similarity for all indexes by specifying the value for *index.similarity.default.type* in the config file :

Example:

```
index.similarity.default.type: BM25
```

Comment: this is well but I want to change default elastic search settings for all new indexes.

Comment: hmm that was already in the document you linked in the original post.. i have updated the answer however as per documentation recommended way to [configure index modules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/index-modules.html#index-modules) is when creating  index

Comment: You can now update an existing index by closing it before setting the similarity. I added the code in another answer

Answer (score 4):

Following up on keety's answer, you can now (ES6) change similarity of an existing indexing by first closing it, changing the similarity and opening it again. from the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/index-modules-similarity.html#default-base):

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/index/_close"
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/index/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "index": {
    "similarity": {
      "default": {
        "type": "classic"
      }
    }
  }
}
'
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/index/_open"
```

Answer (score 2):

Keety's answer is correct but you can also try using index templates.

Index templates allow to define templates that will automatically be applied to new indices created. The templates include both settings and mappings, and a simple pattern template that controls if the template will be applied to the index created.

In your case :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
  "template" : "te*",
  "settings": {
    "similarity": {
      "default": { 
        "type": "BM25"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Defines a template named template_1, with a template pattern of te*. The settings and mappings will be applied to any index name that matches the te* template.

For more information about Index Templates, you can read the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html).